# Error handling from backend to fronted (javascript) using enums, where do I put translations?

Tags: c#, javascript, error-handling, translation

I'm tinkering with an error system where I use enums to identify errors. The enums are contained serverside and converted into JS objects, but I don't know where to keep my error messages.

Errors enum

```
public enum MyError
{
    InvalidThingFormat = 1001,
    AllowedThingsExceeded = 1002
}
```

Generated JavaScript "enum"

```
var MyError= {InvalidThingFormat :1001,AllowedThingsExceeded:1002};
```

And do checking like

```
switch(data.error) {
    case MyError.InvalidThingFormat:
        alert("Format validation failed");
        break;
    // etc.
}
```

So far I like how this feels but I don't like the hardcoded error messages; so where would I put my localization/internationalization of the human readable error message?

Should there also be a backend translation set that I push out in JS or should the translations be only on the JS side, handled by some other method? What would the code look like; `Error.GetMessage(MyError.AllowedThingsExceeded)`?

Comment: From a JS point of view, I'd prefer to have the error messages returned with the json representing your errors. Are the numeric codes important on the client?

Comment: I believe a common pattern is to store each localization in a separate file, and include it when necessary. So instead of having hard-coded messages in the error handling method, you would be looking the value up from an object set up in a separate script.

Comment: Eventually I just did what @Jørgen suggested. For translations embedded into JS, I just decided to store them in resource files and generate the JS with the translations directly in them. This might be an issue for caching, but I don't really care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have several javascript files, each named for their localization. IE:

en-us.js:

```
var ErrorMessages = {
    "1001" : "Invalid thing",
    "1002" : "Too many things."
};
```

es-mx.js: (Note, I don't actually know spanish)

```
var ErrorMessages = {
    "1001" : "Cosa no válido",
    "1002" : "Demasiadas cosas"
};
```

So on and so forth.

So you would include en-us.js as a default, then after that, include whatever the appropriate localization is.

You could then use it like so:

```
 var errMsg = ErrorMessages[MyError.InvalidThingFormat];
```

or

```
 var errMsg = ErrorMessages["1001"];
```